# How do I make data-parsley-errors-container="#element" go away after all errors are resolved?

Tags: javascript, parsley.js

How do I set the error container style to display none after all the error messages have been resolved?
I am using `data-parsley-errors-container="#element"` to create a `div` area at the top of my form.  I want to apply a background color to it, but when I do, after all errors messages `<li>` are removed I am left with all the `<ul>` which has the effect of an empty `div` area with a colored background.

Comment: I know I can apply a background color and styling to .parsley-errors-list.filled, but this creates multiple divs one for each error on a huge form. I want one nice looking styled div that holds all error msgs and then shrinks as error are resolved and then goes away completely when all are resolved.  I have it working now except for how do I make it go away?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the HTML and JavaScript that you are using

Answer (score 1):

I had something similar issue, below is my work-around :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {


    $('#formId').parsley().subscribe('parsley:field:error', function () {

       $('#errorDiv').css({
            "display": "block"
            }); 
       });

    $('#formId').parsley().subscribe('parsley:field:success', function () {

        var totalErrorCount = $("#filterErrorDiv li").length;
        if(totalErrorCount == 0)
        {
            $('#errorDiv').css({
                "display": "none"
            });
        }

      });
  });
```

If any field has error then error event listner displays the errorDiv.
For every field validation success the second listener checks for existing error-count and hides the errorDiv if there is no error remaining.